# get the previous element value with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a wordpress page on which products are shown with ajax add to cart action. I want to get the value of input with name=quantity when button is clicked. I want to do this with jquery prev() function as there are many other inputs with same attributes. So how can i do that? I have

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
     e(document).on("click",".add_to_cart_button",
          function(){
          var t=e(this);   
})})



<form action="/shop/?add-to-cart=1732" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="quantity buttons_added">
       <input type="button" value="-" class="minus">
       <input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text">
       <input type="button" value="+" class="plus">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" data-product_id="1732" data-product_sku="menu-aug-02" data-quantity="1" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</button></form>
```

Comment: Which element to you have a reference to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    ...
    ...

    var prevInput = $(this).prev().children('input[name=quantity]');    // This is what you need


    // Try with this 
    var requiredInput;
    $(this).prev().children().each(function() {
        if($(this).attr('name') != null)
        {
            requiredInput = $(this);
        }
    });

    ...
    ...
});
```

**API**
[prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)
[children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)

Comment: Do you need the click event on 'submit' or on 'plus' -- I guess plus is just to expand some details? Is it?

Comment: I want the text of the input and not its value!

Comment: What do you mean by "text of the input"?

Comment: I mean the value being seen in the input box! On plus minus it is being changed!

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$('.plus').on('click',function(){
     var qty = $('input[name="quantity"]').val();
     alert(qty);
});
```

You can also try with `.before()` like

```
$('.plus').on('click',function(){
     var qty = $(this).before('input[name="quantity"]').val();
     alert(qty);
});
```

with `.prev()` like

```
$('.plus').on('click',function(){
     var qty = $(this).prev('input[name="quantity"]').val();
     alert(qty);
});
```

If you want it on submit try like

```
$('.cart').on('submit',function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var qty = $(this).prev('input[name="quantity"]').val();
     alert(qty);
});
```